# Datatables Jquery capture clicking on pagination buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to uncheck header checkbox while traversing pages in paginated datatable, i.e. suppose i have checked the header checkbox and traversed to next or last page using the pagination buttons, now i want the header checkbox to be unselected.
Appreciate help in advance.

Regards,

Vaibhav

Comment: show your code please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in the fnDrawCallback function

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
    $("#select-all-header").removeAttr("checked");
}
```