# how to find id based on pagination

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, pagination, datatables

I am using the [jQuery DataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) on a JSF `<h:dataTable>`. In this page I have 86 records.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id  +    Name    +   Email        +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1  +   Name 1   +  Email 1       +
+  2  +   Name 2   +  Email 2       +
+  3  +   Name 3   +  Email 3       +
+........
+  4  +   Name 4   +  Email 4       +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                 1.2.3.4..... Next +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Note: Per table I am showing 10 records.**

What my client want is add a column Views which will work as below.

When I open table I have 10 records, means id 1-10 get 1 view.

When I click pagination 2, id 11-20 get 1 view.

Any idea how to get this done?

---

### Edit 1

### What I meant by `get 1 view` is as below.

User A : When page is opened, default pagination 1 is ON. So on page we have 10 records. Means all 10 records are viewed by user A, means each id get 1 view. SO now id 1-10 have 1 views. User A exits the page.

User B : When page is opened, default pagination 1 is ON. So on page we have 10 records. Means all 10 records are viewed by user B, means each id get 1 view. SO now id 1-10 have 2 views (as user A has already viewed). Now User B clicks pagination 2 button. So id 11-20 get view 1. User B exits the page.

This way I want to calculate views per id.

### **So basically what I want is**

- When pagination button is pressed, I want to get ids that are on the table.
- Pass those ids to some bean and increase those id's views.

Any idea how to get this done?

---

### Edit 2

Also check this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934279/1066828

Here I found all solution...

Comment: Sorry for that but I couldn't understand what `get 1 view` means. If user clicks pagination 2 (s)he gets 11-20 ok this is default right? :)

Comment: Thanks for well explanation. Sounds like doable with `fnDrawCallback` but it requires being so deep about jQuery datatables.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı : ANy link for help would be appreciated. or Demo from you would also help me.

Comment: I'll share when I'll be home in a hour.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı : Okay, great.

Comment: You can try: <p:ajax event="page" to solve that.

Comment: @RongNK : I am not using Primefaces. Normal h:datatable

Comment: @Fahim Parkar: what approaches did you use ?(for paging)

Comment: @RongNK : For paging I used dataTable (provided link in question) <h:dataTable>

Comment: Wow, i had never worked with it, sorry !

Comment: @RongNK : its ok... if I had paging based on parameters in link, It would have been easy...

Comment: I suggest a simple solution, when user click for paging, you trigger event (button click), and submit next page index to server via that event.

Comment: Hi, You can use something like [primefaces lazy page loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf) so when the user presses the button your method will be called and you know exacly at render time which rows have been shown

Comment: @FahimParkar sorry for delay, these are what I'have found [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235332/datatables-jquery-capture-clicking-on-pagination-buttons) and [2](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/57/fndrawcallback/p1).

Comment: @RuntimeError : On pressing next, which action will get called? Any idea? I am not getting it...

Comment: @Fahim Parkar : In the primefaces example when you press next/forward it calls this function 'public List<Car> load(..)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching about pagination with [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/), found lot's of great stuff, for example this guy Todd. A. Wood made a great job about loading data with PetaPoco while paging [here](http://www.woodcp.com/2012/02/server-side-paging-with-petapoco-and-datatables/). But it's complicated even when it's compared with your requirement. I have to confess DataTables got great documentation, and I found the answer [pagination plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api).

So the magic function is: `fnPagingInfo`. But, for getting the page info the datatable render(or re-render) event must be captured via `fnDrawCallback`.

Anyway you should embed below codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
    {
        return {
            "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
            "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
            "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
            "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
            "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
            "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                    0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
            "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                    0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
        };
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                var input = document.getElementById('form:Fenerbahce');
                input.value = this.fnPagingInfo().iPage;
            }
        } );
    });

</script>
```

As can be seen the first part means definiton of `fnPagingInfo`. In the second part `fnDrawCallback` captures the render event and we are putting the value of input which is:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="Fenerbahce" value="#{bean.var1}" style="display:none;"></h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

**So what we got so far?**

We got the information of page number which clicked by User and put this number into our `bean`. Rest of it storing the number for each page and counting them in an array when someone clicks:

```
public void setVar1(String var1) {
    this.var1 = var1;
    Array[var1]++;
}
```

Note: I've tried this via basic HTML table like:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>etc</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        <td>etc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        <td>etc</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With lot's of rows of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check answer and get back to you incase of any queries

Comment: yep, not yet implemented.. working on some other projects... may be will get back to you after a week.. thanks for checking...

Comment: today I am trying to implement... :)

Comment: this helped me lot... but I want to know the data that is there in second column... any idea how to get that done? I want to know the data in second column...

Comment: can u take at new question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897530/displaying-data-of-datatable-column

Comment: @FahimParkar I am glad to hear that helped. But after months it is hard to re-implement this for me. Also if it is helped do not grudge few reps please :)

Comment: ok, thanks... I have marked it accepted now.. But if you research and find out for me it would be great...