# Passing <br /> in bean variable to print in <h:outputLabel />

Tags: java, html, jsf-2, javabeans

What I have is `<h:outputLabel value="#{userInfo.totalExp}" />`

Below is what I want as output

```
Total - 10 Years 2 Months
U.A.E - 5 Years 0 Months
India - 5 Years 2 Months
```

For this in bean, I was passing data as

```
totalExp = "Total - 10 Years 2 Months<br />U.A.E - 5 Years 0 Months<br />India - 5 Years 2 Months"
```

However I see output as `Total - 10 Years 2 Months<br />U.A.E - 5 Years 0 Months<br />India - 5 Years 2 Months` instead of above. This gives output U.A.E in same line instead of next line.

Any idea how to get the data in next line?

---

### Edit 1

When I use `\n` instead of `<br />`, I still get data in one line as ``.

When I view source of page, I see it as below.

```
<label dir="LTR">
Total - 10 years &amp; 7 months 
Ok OK
Teset</label>
```

means enter is present... Does that mean `label` is not allowing enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF escapes by default [XML entites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) like `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;` in order to prevent [XSS attack holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf) being introduced by ignorant starters.

You can turn off XML escaping on a per-component basis using the `escape` attribute.

```html
<h:outputLabel ... escape="false" />
```

The same attribute is also present in `<h:outputText>` and a few others.

Actually, I believe that you're currently abusing the `<h:outputLabel>` for the wrong purpose. It generates namely a [HTML `<label>` element](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/label/) which is supposed to be associated with a HTML input element via `for` attribute. But the text as you've there does not seem to represent a valid label, also the `for` attribute is absent. Rather use `<h:outputText>` instead then.

Comment: Thanks for kind help. Its working. Also will keep in mind your note of `outputText`

Comment: Can you take a look at my [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192543/how-to-find-id-based-on-pagination)